# Making a transparent globe in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: cartography, arcgis-pro, transparency-opacity, globe, global-scene

In ArcGIS Pro (2.1), I'm attempting to create a 3D scene in which the underlying basemap is transparent such that I can see through the oceans.

I'm trying to get an effect similar to **[this](https://www.pixelsquid.com/png/wire-frame-globe-with-transparent-water-1318203588941452966?image=G01)**.

Or this:

[image]

I've created a 3D Scene in ArcGIS Pro with just a basemap.

[image]

Reducing the  the transparency to 50% just fades the basemap and doesn't actually make it transparent.

[image]
If I turn the basemap off completely, I just get a white globe.

[image]

And adding a vector layer of countries results in this:
[image]

Is there a way to achieve a transparent globe in ArcGIS Pro? Or is this something that hasn't been implemented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set Surface color to no color under Map Properties: Scene

[image]

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thank you. For some reason, looking for this in Elevation Surface was not obvious to me. It's also worth noting that for good results, I had to play around with the Illumination settings.